# What does "/" do in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I reviewing some PL/SQL code and I came across the following in the scripts:

```
/
SHOW error

grant execute on someName1 to someName2;

/
SHOW error
```

Reviewing the documentation for PL/SQL I could not find an explanation what the /'s do.

Can anyone enlighten me?

- Update:  I opened the file that includes this script in SQL Developer for Mac.  Compiling it gives the error "encountered the symbol '/'".  Should these slashes be removed?

Comment: Just a note: `SHOW error` is also a SQL Plus command, not part of PL/SQL. As to whether the `/` should be removed, how are the scripts generally used, if working with a team, there needs to be some agreement about tools and how scripts will be constructed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"/" executes the sql command in the current buffer. It similar to GO of SQL Server

Comment: Does "buffer" correspond to "batch" in SQL Server?

Comment: Go in SQL Server or to be exact in T-SQL shows the end of the scope of a batch so I think it cannot be similar to / in PL/SQL! Would you please explain a little bit more.

Answer (score 4):

The slash basically executes the latest command stored in the buffer.

It's kind of a clunky thing, but a lot of PL/SQL interpreters/engines like SQL Plus require you to enter a "/" after every complete statement to actually execute it and see the results.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b31189/ch12004.htm#SQPUG162